# Zoopla PEM Certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, pem, csr

I am trying to get zoopla rtdf connected and have a question about their PEM certification process on their Sandbox.

Once the CSR (generated by user) is uploaded via Zooplas CSR signing page they send you a 12 digit success token response ...which I have.

In the docs they then say they will contact you verbally to verify you are real by asking for your token number as above. All good in theory but how do they contact you when they have not taken or requested a tel number or even an email address. Nor do they now even provide s technical contact number or email. Very Confused!!

Here is their documentation.

https://realtime-listings.webservices.zpg.co.uk/docs/latest/documentation.html

Go to section 3 and you will see the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

When you create the CSR you can insert your email address into the file as you create it.  And if I remember correctly the csr submission page will ask you for a contact number.  HTH